# Counting the spaces in a string

Tags: java, comparison, string

I want to count the spaces in a string:

```
public class SongApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "a b c";

        int i =0,spaceCount=0;

        while(i<word.length()){

            char temp = word.charAt(i);         
            System.out.println(temp);
            if(" ".equals(temp)){
                spaceCount++;
            }
            i++;            
        }
        System.out.println("Spaces in string: "+spaceCount);
    }
}
```

When I replace the if statement with `if(temp.equals(" "))`, I get a "cannot invoke(String) on the primitive type char.

I don't understand why this won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't work because you are calling a method of Class String (equals()) on a value which is of primitive type 'char'. You are trying to compare a 'char' with a 'String'.

You must compare between 'char's and since it's a primitive value you need to use '==' boolean compare operator like:

```
public class SongApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String word = "a b c";
      int i = 0,
      spaceCount = 0;

      while( i < word.length() ){
        if( word.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
            spaceCount++;
        }
        i++;
      }

      System.out.println("Spaces in string: "+spaceCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace function for String to replace all the spaces(" ") with no spaces("") and get the difference between the lengths before and after calling the replace function. 
Go through this example:

```
class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String s1 = "a b c";
        int s1_length = s1.length();
        System.out.println(s1_length); // 5

        String s2 = s1.replace(" ",""); 
        int s2_length = s2.length();
        System.out.println(s2_length); // 3

        System.out.println("No of spaces = " + (s1_length-s2_length)); // No of spaces = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use commons-lang.jar to calculate this.

`public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "a b c";
    System.out.println("Spaces in string: " + StringUtils.countMatches(word," "));
}
```

}`

The source of "StringUtils.countMatches" is below:

```
public static int countMatches(String str, String sub) {
    if (isEmpty(str) || isEmpty(sub)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    while ((idx = str.indexOf(sub, idx)) != INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
        count++;
        idx += sub.length();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class CountSpace {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word = "a b c";
    String data[];int k=0;
    data=word.split("");
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i].equals(" ")){
            k++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(k);

}
```

}